# Achieving even interval image capture on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, embedded, embedded-resource

I'm currently working with a Raspberry Pi 3 and a Raspberry Pi Camera Rev 2.0 and I have a trouble implementing a 10 fps interval capture.

I was able to find codes where I achieved 68.7fps on the raspbian. However, for my project, I need to implement an image capture with an interval, to be exact 10 fps, and when I tried to manually intervene with capture_sequence or capture_continuous with time.sleep() I was only able to achieve 2 fps the most.

Here is what I have currently:

```
import picamera
from time import time, sleep, gmtime, strftime

def wait():
    sleep(0.05)

with picaemra.PiCamera() as camera:
    # Camera Initialization HERE
    camera.resolution = (256, 256)
    camera.framerate = 80
    camera.start_preview()
    sleep(1)

    start = time()
    for filename in camera.capture_continuous('./testFolder/image{timestamp:%H:%M:%S.%f}.jpg'):
        finish = time()
        print('Captured %s at %.2ffps' % (filename, 1 / (finish - start)))
        wait()
        start = time()
```

This code above inconsistently produces about 2 .jpg images per second. How should I approach this in order to achieve the 10 fps I need? If I run the code above, the result is as the following:

```
Captured ./testFolder/image21:26:52.049541.jpg at 2.00fps
Captured ./testFolder/image21:26:52.509880.jpg at 2.15fps
Captured ./testFolder/image21:26:52.979726.jpg at 2.15fps
Captured ./testFolder/image21:26:53.449143.jpg at 2.15fps
Captured ./testFolder/image21:26:53.920399.jpg at 2.17fps
```

Also, when using capture_continous(), would I be able to limit the number of photos being taken?

It'd be a great help if anyone were to answer this or even give me a clue to where I should do more search on.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys,
I've found the answer myself.

All I've done was to add

```
use_video_port=True
```

as an option for capture_continuous.

This increased the frame rate to about 20~50 and I just had to add some delay based on the duration calculated with time.time()

For further explanation, 10 fps means that I have to capture 1 image per 0.1 second; therefore, all I had to do was to do sleep( 0.1 - {duration_calculated} ) for each loop allowing the implementation I've needed.

I hope this comes to help for anyone in need :)